# How to create a custom related manager in Django?

Tags: django, django-managers

```
class ModelA(Model):
    pass

class ModelB(Model):
    modela = ForeignKey(ModelA, on_delete=CASCADE)

class ModelC(Model):
    modelb = ForeignKey(ModelB, on_delete_CASCADE)
```

In this case Django will automatically create a few additional managers for us. For example, if `ma` is an instance of `ModelA`, then we can write: `ma.modelb_set.all()`, and if `mb` is an instance of `ModelB`, then we can write: `mb.modelc_set.all()`.

It would be convenient to be able to reference all `ModelC` instances related to `ModelA`. Of course, if `ma` is an instance of `ModelA`, we can always write: `ModelC.objects.filter(modelb__modela=ma).distinct()`. However, it would be more convenient if we could define a manager for `ModelA` that would allow us to execute the above query by simply writing: `ma.modelc_set.all()`

How to write such a manager for `ModelA`?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really the job of a manager, but just a normal model method. Since you're looking for items that are related to a specific instance of ModelA, you can make a method on that model. If you really want, you can call it `modelc_set` and make it a property:

```
@property
def modelc_set(self):
    return ModelC.objects.filter(modelb__modela=self).distinct()
```

Comment: OK, thank you for your answer. In that case, however, why are Django’s default managers for reversing one-to-many relationships managers and not properties?

Comment: One thing you can’t do with properties: `prefetch_related('modelc_set')`